# Extract tar file without creating folder

Tags: unix, tar, archiving

I want to extract tar file in Unix **tar xvf /home/test/group.tar** and once extracted got a folder **group** which has list of xls,pdf,txt files.

How can i extract contents of group.tar inside **/home/test/list of xls, pdf files** without creating group folder.

Any specific command available or have to follow with copy and move??

Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

You may use the `--strip-components 1` parameter.

```
tar xvf group.tar --strip-components 1
```